# C# If Loop Condition Question (shouldn't this be an infinite loop?)

Tags: c#

I have this code and it wants to know what is logged to the console.

```
private static int Printer (int j)
{
    for(var i = j; i > 0; i = Printer(i - 1))
    {
        Console.Write(i);
    }

    return j;
}

Printer(2)
```

Apparently this returns 211, but why does this not create an infinite loop since Printer(anyNumber) will always return a 2 thus assigning i to always be > 0?

Comment: `since Printer(anyNumber) will always return a 2` What? No. It returns `j`.

Comment: What argument are you passing into `Printer` initially?

Comment: `Printer` doesn't always return 2, it returns the number you pass to it. And in the for loop, you pass `i-1` to next call, so the number is decreasing, till it calls `Printer(0)`, which will terminates the loop

Comment: You can easily step through the code in the debugger to see what's going on. Or use a small number (as you are doing) and just do it on paper. It's pretty strait forward.

Comment: Pass in `2`, `i` is initialized to `2`, `Console.Write(2)` is called, then `Printer(1)` is called in the `for` loop, `Console.Write(1)` is called, then `Printer(0)` is called in the `for` loop and the condition `i > 0` fails, so the stack unwinds. Then the next iteration of the `for` loop executes with `i == 1`, `Console.Write(1)` is called (followed by a recursive call to `Printer(0)` again), and then the `for` loop finally ends because `x > 0` fails. So the output is `211`

Comment: See [this fiddle](https://rextester.com/JABA71124) - I added some diagnostic logging to help you understand the flow.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

I already started an answer, so I thought I'd post it here. Maybe it will help to see it written another way?

This is a good time to get to know your debugger. You can easily step through the code in to see what's going on (how the values are changing during the recursive calls, etc).

To illustrate why `211` is output when you call `Printer(2)`:

0. `Printer(2)` is called from `Main()`
1. `i` is initialized to `2`
2. `i > 0` is `true`
3. `Console.Write(2)` is called
4. `i = Printer(i - 1)` is executed (in the `for` loop)
5. `Printer(1)` is called (recursively from step `4`)
6. `i` is initialized to `1`
7. `i > 0` is `true`
8. `Console.Write(1)` is called
9. `i = Printer(i - 1)` is executed (in the `for` loop)
10. `Printer(0)` is called  (recursively from step `9`)
11. `i` is initialized to `0`
12. `i > 0` is `false`
13. `0` is returned; stack unwinds to step `9`
14. `i = 0` assignment is made
15. `i > 0` is `false`
16. `1` is returned; stack unwinds to step `4`
17. `i = 1` assignment is made
18. `i > 0` is `true`
19. `Console.Write(1)` is called
20. `i = Printer(i - 1)` is executed (in the `for` loop)
21. `Printer(0)` is called  (recursively from step `20`)
22. `i = 0` assignment is made
23. `i > 0` is `false`
24. `0` is returned; stack unwinds to step `20`
25. `i = 0` assignment is made
26. `i > 0` is `false`
27. `2` is returned; control goes back to `main()` from step `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a debugger to step through the code and see for your self. I suggest to learn to use a debugger. *Depending who you ask what I just said is not a good answer. So, either I want to provide a better explanation, or the rest of the answer is me flexing… Let us say a little bit of both.*

---

We set `i=j`. And we check `i>0`.

That check can be either `true` or `false`.

---

If that is `false` (i.e. if `i` is less or equal to `0`) we return `j`. That is our exit condition.

---

Otherwise, we recursively call the function with `i-1`, which will be our new value for `j`.

But what is the value of `j`? The first time your code runs, `j` will have some value… Let us call it `j₀`. Then `i=j` means that `i=j₀`. Thus, we are calling the function with `j₀-1`. Let us call it `j₁`

As long as `i>0` continues to be `true`, we would have `j₂ = j₁ - 1`, `j₃ = j₂ - 1` and so on… The general formula is `jₙ = jₙ₋₁ - 1`.

Observe that this formula is decreasing, thus it will eventually result in a value less or equal to `0` (which is our exit condition). Thus, we know that the recursion ends.

---

Since the function will only do something interesting when the initial value is greater than `0`. From now on we will assume that `j₀` is greater than `0` (other wise the code output nothing, and that's it).

Now that I know that the sequence ends, I will flip the nomenclature. Let `N` be `j₀`. Let `N-1` be `j₁` and so on. The last value is `N-N`, that is `0`. Why? Because as the values decrease `0` is the first value that is not greater than `0`. *That is the first value that will not produce an output. The last output is `1`.*

---

What does the function return? `return j`. And `j` is whatever input the function got, since `j` is not modified. Thus the function returns whatever input it got. *And output some values.*

Since we will be passing `i-1`, we know that it will be returning `i-1`. Thus the values of `i` decrement. Thus, we know that the iteration also ends. Since both recursion and iteration ends, we know the code terminates.

---

So, the first time `i=j` gives `i` the value `N`. And we check `i>0`. Remember that for the sake of argument we are saying that `N` is greater than `0` (otherwise the code returns and that's it).

Then we call the function recursively with `i-1`, which we called `N-1`. And since the function returns whatever value it got, it will return `N-1`. Then we print that value. And repeat.

So far, we know that the output of the function follows this order:

```
N
(some values)
N-1
(some values)
N-2
(some values)
·
·
·
```

But how does those `(some values)` look like? Well, the same. Since the sequence is recursive, the sequence is fractal (self-similar).

```
N
(values for N-1)
N-1
(values for N-2)
N-2
(values for N-3)
·
·
·
1
```

Thus the sequence ends like this:

```
·
·
·
4
3
2
1
1
2
1
1
3
2
1
1
2
1
1
```

It can be easier to understand with some indentation:

```
4
 3
  2
   1
  1
 2
   1
 1
3
  2
   1
  1
2
 1
1
```

Or some ASCII art:

```
·           ·
·           ·
·           ·
4-----------+
3--------+  |
2        |  |
1        |  |
1        |  |
2        |  |
1        |  |
1--------+  |
3--------+  |
2 ----+  |  |
1     |  |  |
1 ----+  |  |
2 ----+  |  |
1 -+  |  |  |
1 -+ -+ -+ -+
```

There we see that:

1. When we call the function with the value `1`, the sequence is `1`.
2. When we call it with the value `2` the sequence is `2 (values for 1) 1` that is `211`.
3. When we call it with the value `3` the sequence is `3 (values for 2) 2 (values for 1) 1` that is `3211211`.
4. When we call it with the value `4` the sequence is `4 (values for 3) 3 (values for 2) 2 (values for 1) 1` that is `432112113211211`.

[You can try it online](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOyQExAagB8ABAJgEYBYAKBuPIDYACAS0xiYAUE34EmAFLyYArAJQ0A3jSaymAMwD2CAQDcI/FkwC8ogNysmAPiYAGA1t3deiIUwC0TcmInU5TaW/dyAwosxQigA2cAB0AOo88EJiejJyAL408bLEAOz6NEm01NbstgAssUA==).

*No it does not output `212`. If anything it ends in `211` for any input greater or equal to `2`. How did you get `212`?*

---

Let me flip the order of the sequence and express it like this `112112311211234`. It can be easier to grasp this way:

1. Start with the number 1.
2. Duplicate the sequence.
3. Add the next number.
4. Go to step 2.

So `1`, then `11`, then `112`, then `112112` then `1121123` then `11211231121123` then `112112311211234` and so on.

Searching that on the The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences I find it is cataloged as [A082850](http://oeis.org/A082850). There you can see alternative ways to get the same sequence.

---

Comment: I don't know what is worst case of gate keeping "go learn to use a debugger" or "let me stumble down this poorly written explanation that makes it look harder than it is". In my defense: I tried.

Comment: No worries, I'll look it over and try to understand it. You're right, it's 211. Not sure why I had 212 in my head.